# Missing all payloads containing empty array on submit Laravel Inertiajs Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-10

I have a weird problem on Laravel 10 Inertiajs, I have reactjs form with states look like this

```
const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: '',
    category_id: '',
    price: '',
    choices:[],
    images:[],
    deleted_choices:[],
    deleted_images:[],
});
```

The images state contains base 64 image string.
The problem is if I add an image to the images state and let other state with empty array, they are  missing on submit to backend.
I did `console.log` before submit, the empty arrays are still exists, but on backend they are gone. so in this case, choices, deleted_choices, and deleted_images are missing.

```
const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Check Submit', data, processing)
        post(route('save_item'));
    };
```

But if images state array stays empty, no missing on backend even if other array state are empty.
Any idea what wrong?

Comment: try to create `new FormData()` and then `append` all your inputs values to the formData